# Binding bridge to specific host nic

Tags: vagrant

When I use:

```
config.vm.network :public_network
```

It asks me which nic to bridge against.

How do I set that up in the Vagrantfile so I don't have to choose on vagrant up

Answer (score 0):

We're on Vagrant 1.4.3, and use the *bridge* and *adapter* options:

```
config.vm.network :public_network, :bridge => 'eth1', :adapter => 2

where: 
   :bridge  - specifies the host adapter to use
   :adapter - specifies the guest network interface to use
```